# Rails form_tag post not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, post

My users_controller has these methods

```
  def follow_code
    @user = current_user
  end

  def followsubmit
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

My route file has

```
  match "follow_code" => "users#follow_code", :as => "follow_code"
  match "follow_code" => 'users#followsubmit', :as => "follow_code", :via => 'post'
```

My follow_code.html.erb view has

```
<%= form_tag(follow_code_path, :method => 'post') do %>
    <%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
<% end %>
```

Yet for some reason when I click submit on my view I am never redirected to my root_path and instead the follow_code view is re-rendered.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also curious about this. I ran into it today, using match as well, and my solution was to rename the post action:

```
 match "follow_code" => "users#follow_code", :as => "follow_code"
 match "save_follow_code" => 'users#followsubmit', :as => "save_follow_code", :via => 'post'
```

However, I was using the condition attribute to specify the method. In your case, you may just need to specify the first one as a get.

```
match "follow_code" => "users#follow_code", :as => "follow_code", :via => 'get'
match "follow_code" => 'users#followsubmit', :as => "follow_code", :via => 'post'
```